# Repeat a task for every 10 seconds using Threads and services in android

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I called two Web serivces when app started, and those are running in background.

each service is taking about 35-40 seconds approximately. until these service completed i am showing a loader on clicking each Tab, where i have 4 acitvities in my TabActiviy.
when ever these services completed i hide the loader and showing the data.

Now,my Question is? while services are running in background by any chance if Network have failed?, how i have to intimate to user by dialogbox that process is interupted by Network.

May i have chance to check network connection by every 10 sec or less in android?
so that i can intimate to user with a dialog and resume the services?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you use HTTP connection - surround with try-catch block your network data and show error message if some thing happened.

Add `Runnable` target to your `Service`

```
new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            if(socket.isConnected()){

            }else{
                // show error and call dialog
            }
        }
    }
};
```

if are you working with sockets

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and the Android [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html):

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(checkCon, 10, 10);

private boolean checkCon() {
  ConnectivityManager conMgr =  (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

  if ( conMgr.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED 
      &&  conMgr.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

`checkCon()` returns `false` if the Connection to Mobile (conMgr.getNetworkInfo(0)) AND Wifi (conMgr.getNetworkInfo(1)) is disconnected.

Comment: thanks sani this code works excellent for refreshing. now my problem is how to display dialog box when network not available. i am getting problem with this because while webservices are running in background i can navigate from one tab to another tab in my application,as Dialog box in android required context which context i have to send to dialog box where i have 4 tab activities in my tab activity.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try of following code .

```
TimerTask refresher;


                  // Initialization code in onCreate or similar:

                  timer = new Timer();    
                  refresher = new TimerTask() {
                      public void run() {
                          handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                      };
                  };
                  // first event immediately,  following after 1 seconds each
                  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(refresher, 0, 65); 


 @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
        final Handler handler = new Handler() {
             public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                 switch (msg.what) {
                 case REFRESH:


                     break;
                 default:
                     break;
                 }
             }
         };
```

its worked for me like a charm.. Hope this will help you .

Comment: thanks Rajesh this code works excellent for refreshing. now my problem is how to display dialog box when network not available. i am getting problem with this because while webservices are running in background i can navigate from one tab to another tab in my application,as Dialog box in android required context which context i have to send to dialog box where i have 4 tab activities in my tab activity.

Comment: hi you can use Broadcast receiver for finding whether network is available or not..